# assign a running number on variables in python df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

## evaluating calibration data

For a system calibration I need to compare reference ('ref') and test ('test') variables. df looks like this (section out of a df with >3000 variables):

```py
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    df
Time    ref     test
sec     Q       Q
1       nan     nan
2       nan     nan
3       5,00    4,89
4       5,08    5,00
5       4,93    4,97
6       nan     nan
7       nan     nan
8       14,83   14,96
9       14,87   15,13
10      14,72   14,83
11      nan     nan
12      nan     nan
13      nan     nan
14      nan     nan
15      24,37   24,35
16      24,29   24,39
17      24,28   24,50
18      24,26   24,41
19      nan     nan
```

For comparing the variables 'ref' and 'test' I need to extract the plains with hysteresis. Could do it manual:

```py
    grades = []
    for row in df['ref']:
        if row < 5,5:
            grades.append('A')
        elif row < 15,5:
            grades.append('B')
        elif row < 26:
            grades.append('C')
        else:
            grades.append('Failed') 
    df['Result_Ref'] = grades
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

But the function should evaluate the 'ref' and 'test' by an hysteresis (+-3%) and assign A, B, C,... automaticly. Result should look like this:

```py
   df
Time    ref     test    Result_Ref
sec     Q       Q
3       5,00    4,89    A
4       5,08    5,00    A
5       4,93    4,97    A
8       14,83   14,96   B   
9       14,87   15,13   B   
10      14,72   14,83   B
15      24,37   24,35   C
16      24,29   24,39   C
17      24,28   24,50   C
18      24,26   24,41   C
```

as time and steps/plains (A, B, C, ....Z) are unlimited (up to 20), the function I'm searching for should search in the df ('ref', 'test') for next (big) step. Something like

```py
when x(i+1)>x(i)), than append('A:Z')
```

and assign a running variable (1,2,3,.. or A, B, C,..) into column 'Result_Rev'.

Here is the complete graph to this point
[full calibration with extracted plains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cekDG.png)
As I'm quite new to python I have no clue about such a functiont ;) Thx in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will get much more help if you have a go yourself and then, if you run into difficulties, post a question about the specific problem. SO users don't write code for you.

Comment: means also to write how i got to the first df (the program steps inbetween)? just wanted to reduce the post length cause i'm solving most functions by math operations. but thx for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a [rolling difference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff):

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df['diff'] = df['ref'].diff()
```

You might prefer a discrete derivative.
Just divide by the time difference.

With that in hand, how would you assign a running variable showing the step number?

Please edit your question to reflect the code you're currently working with,
or ideally post an answer to your own question.
(Yes, SO *encourages* you to answer questions, even a question that you asked!)

Comment: my first intention was:

`def delta(i,x):
    for i in range(i+x, len(df)-x):
        if 0.97*df.loc[i+x,'ref']<=df.loc[i,'ref']<=1.03*df.loc[i+x,'ref']:
           df.loc[i, 'diff']=1
        else:
            df.loc[i,'diff']=0
    return`
but `df['diff'] = df['ref'].diff()`looks nicer.